# Как собирать только измененные файлы в webpack 4?

Tags: javascript, webpack, npm, webpack4

Подскажите, есть ли какой-то способ при сборке (npm run build) в webpack 4 пересобирать только те файлы, в которых были изменения, как это работает при watch? Есть очень много точек входа и каждый раз пересобирать их все занимает много времени.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/only-if-changed-webpack-plugin есть такой плагин

Comment: спасибо, попробую!